# How to validate Radio button with type - button in selenium webdriver.?

Tags: forms, selenium, radio-button, webdriver, junit4

Below is the html code for the radio button.There are three radio buttons in a grid-form binding hrml page of which I want to validate whether the desired radio buton is selected or not.

The webdriver code I used is :-

```
//here totalDivions is an integer value which checks for the number of radio buttons.
for(int j=1;j<=totalDivisions;j++){
    String check = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='radiogroup-1022-bodyEl']/table/tbody/tr/td["+j+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")).getAttribute("checked");
        if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            System.out.println("Checked");
    }
}
```

I have tried using isSelected() but of no use.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code using `isSelected()` method.

```
for(int j=1;j<=totalDivisions;j++){
    boolean check = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='radiogroup-1022-bodyEl']/table/tbody/tr/td["+j+"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/input")).isSelected();
        if( !check )
            System.out.println("Checkbox is not Checked.");
        else
            System.out.println("Checkbox is Checked.");         
    }
```

Comment: Hi Subh, I tried using isSelected() method but it always returns the value false even though if the radio button is selected or not.

Comment: Checkbox is not Checked.
Checkbox is not Checked.
Checkbox is not Checked.

Comment: My bad. :) The parenthesis weren't at proper place. Can you please try now with the updated code above ?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, please provide the HTML code snippet for the radio buttons so that it's possible to enhance our approach

Answer (score 0):

isSelected() is the right method to check if a radio of checkbox is checked or not.
It looks like your page is generated with some JS framework and your page may be not fully generated when the isSelected() method is called.
Anyway do you get an exception when calling it?

Comment: Hello Olivier,I do not get an exception but when I use the isSelected() method it gives me a value as false even though I see that the radio button(of type=button) is selected.

Comment: Weird.  Your xpath expression let me think you are using ExtJS.  Are you sure you are selecting the right input element?
Your code looks fine but you might also try to test your app with Aigrette (available freely on sf.net) and use its input element.
Also you may put some unique class name on your radio in your source file, see what's generated and locate the radio input element.